# select all from one table but compare to multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, join

Hello I have the following query:

```
        SELECT * 
        FROM ams.TestResultHiPot_Archive,ams.unit u
            WHERE timestamp >='3/16/2017 20:39 ' AND timestamp <= '3/17/2017, 20:39' AND LOWER(line_code)=LOWER('aac04') 
            AND LOWER(unitmodelnumber) like LOWER('%%%') AND unitmodelnumber != 'VTI' and u.serial_num=unitserialnumber and u.date_deleted is null
```

this table has many fields so I want to stay away from hard coding each field AND also this structure works for multiple tables.

The only issue I am having is some of the comparison items are in the units table so I want to visit that tablet to compare and if it matches then include that record in my result from the ORIGINALTEST RESULTS ARCHIVE table NOT the units table.

the main issue I am seeing is that the `select *` is causing both tables to return all of their fields.

Is there a way to use select * ,and still compare 2 tables but get the columns ONLY from one table ?

I have tried right join, left join, inner join but nothing seems to work, they all return all the columns from both tables, maybe I have done it incorrectly, or maybe this can't be done?

I also thought maybe doing like a query that selects all the table fields and then storing them in an array and passing that array as my select parameters, that way I am passing the exact needed parameters without hardcoding (since I would always consult the table) but that seems like it would take longer since pgsql is slower. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: use  SELECT {table_alias}.* instead of select * from

Comment: oh wow... that was so much simpler than all the approaches I had considered and tried... I swear I tried something similar but without the ' . ' I saw on another post. Thanks.. a lot that solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select ams.TestResultHiPot_Archive.*
```